# How to increase results MKLocalSearchRequest?

Tags: xcode, mklocalsearchrequest

How does one increase the number of results from a MKLocalSearchRequest?

Here's my code:

```
MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchTextfield.text;
request.region = map.region;

MKLocalSearch *localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    [response.mapItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(MKMapItem *item, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [searchResults addObject:item]; 
    }]; 
}];
```

Everything works beautifully but my region is set as my map region, so if I zoom out one would think more search results would appear but if I look at all of Los Angeles and search 'food', I only get about 10 results, I was hoping for more.

Is pagination involved?

Comment: One doesn't. What you get is what the server gives you.

Comment: You might have to use a third-party API like [Google Maps Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search)